# How do I forbid editing in many_to_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Task model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

User model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
```

Code with issue:

```
<% if current_user == @task.user %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_task_path, class: "btn btn-warning" %>
<% end %>
```

Error says:

> undefined method `user' for #Task:0x007fd9e4f3ceb8

How do I disallow another user (not one of the task owners) to Edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A task has many users, so you can't ask `current_user == @task.user` because `@task.user` doesn't make any sense.

You can do `@task.users`, and in order to check that a user belongs to a particular task, you can do `@task.users.any? { |user| user == current_user }`.

A better approach would be: `current_user.tasks.include? @task`, and it will do the same job but with shorter amount of code.